# MySQL - divide results of count function into columns derived from a separate column

Tags: mysql, count

I recently posted this within a different page of Stack Exchange but believe this to be the more appropriate place for it.

Ok, the title seems abit confusing but I am struggling to put down what I need this query to do so best to explain it. I have 3 tables in my database (Using MySQL Workbench), but for this query I'm just trying to use one. The table named service_data has the following columns:

```
Services_ID|Service_Type|Day|Time|Customer_ID(FK)
1001       |SERVICE1    |Mon|0950|1    
1002       |SERVICE2    |Tue|1032|65
1003       |SERVICE3    |Wed|0859|4
```

the table contains approx 200 records, my aim is to group the timings together, which i have managed to achieve by doing this:

```
select
case 
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '08:00:00' and '09:00:00') then '0800-0900'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '09:00:00' and '10:00:00') then '0900-1000'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '10:00:00' and '11:00:00') then '1000-1100'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '11:00:00' and '12:00:00') then '1100-1200'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '12:00:00' and '13:00:00') then '1200-1300'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '13:00:00' and '14:00:00') then '1300-1400'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '14:00:00' and '15:00:00') then '1400-1500'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '15:00:00' and '16:00:00') then '1500-1600'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '16:00:00' and '17:00:00') then '1600-1700'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '17:00:00' and '18:00:00') then '1700-1800'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '18:00:00' and '19:00:00') then '1800-1900'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '19:00:00' and '20:00:00') then '1900-2000'
WHEN (Delivery_Time between '20:00:00' and '21:00:00') then '2000-2100'
      else 'Outside Opening Hours' 
  end as `Time Period`, 
   count(0) as 'count'
from service_data
group by `Time Period` 
order by count desc 
limit 20;
```

Which produces the below result:

```
TimePeriod  Count 
1700-1800   24
1500-1600   21
1200-1300   19
1400-1500   19
1800-1900   17
1100-1200   17
1300-1400   16
1600-1700   16
1000-1100   16
1900-2000   12
0800-0900   12
0900-1000   11
```

What I am now trying to do is split the count up so that there are 4 columns labelled SERVICE1 SERVICE2 SERVICE3 and SERVICE4 (the values within the Service_Type column. Hopefully so it looks something like this:

```
TimePeriod|SERVICE1|SERVICE2|SERVICE3|SERVICE4
1700-1800 |   6    |   7    |    10  |   1
1500-1600 |   5    |   9    |    1   |   6
1200-1300 |   0    |   4    |    2   |   13`
```

Is this Possible!? I'm sure it must be but i have been pulling my hair out trying to work it out, SQL isn't my first language! Any help would be appreciated

My second issue is:

I would like a second query to be able to do all of the above and then also link the results to a customer_data table who’s primary key customer_id is a foreign key in service_data and link the customer_id to the quadrant (column within customer_data table with values NE,SE,SW,NW dependant on coords) and group the count a second time by quadrant as well as service, so it looks like this:

```
    TimePeriod| SERVICE1  | SERVICE2  | SERVICE3  | SERVICE4  |
   -----------|NE|SE|SW|NW|NE|SE|SW|NW|NE|SE|SW|NW|NE|SE|SW|NW|
    1700-1800 |2 |1 | 0| 3|4 | 0| 0|3 |2 |5 |2 |1 |0 |1 | 0| 0|
```

Again is this possible or am i asking too much? I was wondering if i could use the SUM(IF) function in some way to achieve all this?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: I appreciate the idea, unfortunately due to the nature of this I'm confined to using MySQL

Comment: Faced with that limitation, I would abandon the project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started, although I do agree with @Strawberry that this needs a programming language to do your last step.

This is not in any way optimised for performance or elegance, but I have tested it with your data as given above.

Here's my CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `service_data` (
  `services_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `service_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`services_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

First get your time ranges. I have knocked a second off the to-time so that a time that is bang on the hour doesn't get double counted.

```
create view spans as
  select time(concat(hour(time),':00:00')) as fromtime, 
         time(concat(hour(addtime(time,'00:59:59')),':00:00')) as totime
  from service_data
```

Now look up the time range for each row of data.

```
create view withspans as
  select * from service_data s1
  join spans s2
    on time between fromtime and totime
```

Now summarise the data as input to the pivot.

```
create view summary as
  select fromtime, totime, service_type, count(*) as spancount
  from withspans
  group by fromtime, totime, service_type
```

Now do the pivot via derived tables.

```
select w.fromtime, w.totime,
  s1.spancount as service1,
  s2.spancount as service2,
  s3.spancount as service3,
  s4.spancount as service4
  from summary w
  left join (select * from summary where service_type = 'SERVICE1') s1
    on s1.fromtime=w.fromtime and s1.totime=w.totime
  left join (select * from summary where service_type = 'SERVICE2') s2
    on s2.fromtime=w.fromtime and s2.totime=w.totime
  left join (select * from summary where service_type = 'SERVICE3') s3
    on s3.fromtime=w.fromtime and s3.totime=w.totime
  left join (select * from summary where service_type = 'SERVICE4') s4
    on s4.fromtime=w.fromtime and s4.totime=w.totime
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's a lot to get started with! I will give it a go tonight, although i fear you are both right, it's a very complicated bit of script, for my level anyway. Thanks again.